# error deleting entries in binary files

Tags: c, file

```
system("cls");
            another = 'y';
            while(another == 'y')
            {
                printf("\nEnter name of employee to delete ");
                scanf("%s",empname);
                ft = fopen("Temp.dat","wb");
                rewind(fp);
                while(fread(&e,recsize,1,fp) == 1)
                {
                    if(strcmp(e.name,empname) != 0)
                    {
                        fwrite(&e,recsize,1,ft);
                    }
                }
                fclose(fp);
                fclose(ft);
                remove("EMP.DAT");
                rename("Temp.dat","EMP.DAT");
                fp = fopen("EMP.DAT", "rb+");
                printf("Delete another record(y/n)");
                another = getche();
            }
```

this is a code of deleting an entry from binary file in c using an employee name! but when i want to delete it by emp id it won't delete the entry , but deletes all the contents of the file !

```
case '4':
            system("cls");
            another = 'y';
            while(another == 'y')
            {
                printf("\nEnter employee id to delete ");
                scanf("%d",&empid);
                ft = fopen("Temp.dat","wb");
                rewind(fp);
                while(fread(&e,recsize,1,fp) == 1)
                {
                    if(e.userid!=empid)
                    {
                        fwrite(&e,recsize,1,ft);
                    }
                }
                fclose(fp);
                fclose(ft);
                remove("EMP.DAT");
                rename("Temp.dat","EMP.DAT");
                fp = fopen("EMP.DAT", "rb+");
                printf("Delete another record(y/n)");
                another = getche();
            }
```

Comment: How are the variables `e`, `empname`, and `empid` defined?

Comment: Just guessing: is your `case '4'` followed by the erase command and did your forget a `break` at the end of `case '4'`.

Comment: @AdamLiss e is an object , empname is char and empid is int

Comment: @BryanOlivier there is a break statement after case 4

Comment: It will be more helpful if you show us how you declare them.  If `empname` is truly a `char` (and not a `char *` or an array of `char`) it's a sign of additional problems.  Please see http://sscce.org/ to learn how to ask questions in a way that will get you the answers you need.

Comment: i can mail u ! plz i need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `scanf("%d", empid);` is wrong. In case it is defined as `int empid;` you should get at least a compile warning:

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]
```

The correct way of reading an integer would be:

```
scanf("%d", &empid);
            ^
```

In case `empid` is defined as `char*` or `char[]` you should convert the desired id to integer using `atoi()` when comparing it with the employee's id:

```
if(e.userid!=atoi(empid))
```

Comment: no the emp id is defined as int , and putting & is making the same problm

Comment: Does the problem still happen, or did you fix it after you edited your question?

Comment: yes i edited it above , but still the same problem ! i can mail the source code

Comment: @LazyWorm please post a bigger portion of your code in the question. Make sure to include all relevant variable declarations.

Answer (score 0):

The `scanf` function takes a format string, followed by the *addresses* of the target variables.  So, assuming you've defined `empid` as an `int`, you'd need to change

```
scanf("%d",empid);
```

to

```
scanf("%d", &empid);
```

You didn't see the problem in the code that deletes by name because `empname` is already a pointer to characters.  You *did* remember to allocate memory for it, right?